# Retrofit 2. Как послать запрос в формате JSON без конвертера?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Добрый день, уважаемые кодеры. Как с помощью Retrofit 2 послать простой POST запрос в таком формате?

```
{
  "PasswordReset" : {
      "username" : "string"
  }
}
```

Через GSON все получается, но я не вижу смысла создавать java классы и использовать gson для такого простого запроса. Подскажите что-нибудь, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете формировать такую строку и добавлять её в боди.

```
public interface ScalarService {  
   @POST("path")
   Call<String> getStringScalar(@Body String body);
}
```

Где то в классе где будете формировать запрос:

```
final static String requestBodyMap = "{\"PasswordReset\" : {\"username\" : \"%1$s\"}}";
```

Перед запросом формировать нужный Request body так:

```
String requestBody =  String.format(requestBodyMap, "Ivan");
Call<String> call = service.getStringScalar(requestBody);
```

Больше добавить строку в Body [тут](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-send-plain-text-request-body)

Comment: В Retrofit.Builder() я должен использовать ScalarsConverterFactory?

Comment: да, нужно будет использовать ScalarsConverterFactory

Comment: в ответ от сервера получаю {"error":{"username":["Необходимо заполнить «Номер телефона или e-mail»."]}}. Видимо запрос строится не правильно. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Сложно сказать. Лучше обратитесь к документации этого API или к его разработчикам.

Может быть несуществующий _username_ отправляете? 
Или недостаточное количество информации?